# CLI tool for analyzing pcap captures

Tags: command-line-interface, analysis, packet-capture, pcap, tshark

I am looking for a command line tool that will look at a capture file, tcpdump -w output, and give output equivalent to the information you get in the Wireshark [conversations](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html#ChStatConversationListWindow), and [endpoint](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatEndpoints.html#ChStatEndpointListWindow) statistics.

To give you a little background, I have the output of a large capture (~3GB, in 40 files) that I can't easily transfer to a machine where I can run Wireshark, given the low bandwidth.

Comment: could you perhaps run a tshark or tcpdump filter on the files to reduce them to a more transferable size?

Comment: @Michael Lowman, I was already filtering, and they are still large.  The link in question I am trying to monitor is a ~300kb/s link.  Something was saturating the link, and I was trying to identify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Niall's answer, you might try

```
tshark -r <capture file> -q -z conv,ip
```

The `-q` disables normal output and `-z conv,ip` dumps the IP conversation data. More information can be found in the [man page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) and in [Sake Blok's Sharkfest presentation](http://www.cacetech.com/SHARKFEST.08/D01_Blok_Advanced%20Scripting,%20Command%20Line%20Usage%20with%20tshark.ppt).

Answer (score 2):

There is a command line component to wireshark called tshark which would do what you need. There's better instruction available [here.](http://projects.gemberdesign.com/research/index.php?title=Trace_processing)

Unfortunately, endpoints seem to be only available in the GUI.

Another alternative might be to use X Forwarding to run Wireshark at the far side and forward the GUI to your local desktop. Without knowing what OS you're using on your desktop, I don't know how possible this will be.

**UPDATE:** More detail added as per comment request.

Comment: That is a good start, but would be useful if you could elaborate so the answer will be more complete?

Comment: Sorry, threw that up when running out the door yesterday. More detail added.